# Sylow subgroups of $A_{5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

In particular, I am just looking for the sylow $3$ and sylow $5$ subgroups of $A_{5}$ since I already figured the other case out. Now, for sylow $3$ subgroups I have that $n_{3} = 1$ mod  $3$ and $n_{3} | 20 \Rightarrow n_{3}$ could be $1,4,$ or $10$. Now, from here how do I figure out which one it is without writing all the possible subgroups down to see if they are distinct? In other words, is their a way to pick out the right one without brutal force? If I understand this, I am sure sylow $5$ subgroups will follow similarly.

Comment: Certainly it isn't $1$ since $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: What about the other two?

Comment: The term is "brute force" not "brutal force." :)

Answer (score 1):

a sylow 3-subgroup of $A_5$ is just $\{1,(a b c),(a c b)\}$.  There are $5\cdot4\cdot3/(3\cdot2)=10$ of these.

similarly, the sylow 5-subgroups are just those generated by 5-cycles, of which there are $5!/(5\cdot4)=6$.

Comment: How did you get the number $5!/(5.4)$? Is this some formula in combinatorics?

Comment: @S.D. 5! for the number of lists of length 5, divide by 5 for cyclic permutations of the list, divide by 4 since an element g of order 5 generates the same subgroup as $g$, $g^2$, $g^3$, $g^4$.  In other words 5!/5 counts the elements of order 5, and dividing by 4 collects those in the same subgroup.