# Is there an elegant method to show the alternating group $A_5$ as disjoint union of its Sylow subgroups and the trivial element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Per the discussion in the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616944/how-to-piece-together-the-sylow-subgroups-of-a-5-to-form-the-whole-group) the alternating group $A_5$ is apparently the disjoint union of its Sylow subgroups and the trivial element. I know it can be done explicitly by writing down all the subgroups in terms of their cycle notation. But is there a more elegant way to see this without explicit decompositions?

Comment: The comment of Derek Holt at the duplicate is very useful. Why not write down the Sylow subgroups explicitly for $A_5$? This has been done anyway here, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957713/find-all-the-sylow-2-and-the-sylow-3-subgroups-of-a-5?rq=1) together with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497047/sylow-subgroups-of-a-5?rq=1).

Comment: Reading the title my first thought was "use cycle notation," only to read you've already seen such a proof. I would say it's an elegant proof already, and the most direct and salient route to go.